# What do these numbers in Android logcat mean?

Tags: android, logcat

```
10-21 10:37:32.821  18142-18297/com.myapp.debug D/[111] SqLiteHelper insertArrayList﹕ Start
10-21 10:37:33.422  18142-18291/com.myapp.debug D/[128] SqLiteHelper insertArrayList﹕ Finish
10-21 10:37:33.452  18142-18142/com.myapp.debug D/[89] Screen1 onPause﹕ SQLite db closing
```

These are typical lines from my Android app log.

1. Time (October 21 10:37 am)
2. Mysterious numbers separated by a dash
3. application package (com.myapp.debug)
4. Log type (debug)
5. Header (lineNum, Activity & Method)
6. Body

So these mysterious numbers - are they thread IDs? user IDs? Process IDs? Why do they sometimes change? Why are there 2 of them that are sometimes the same?

Update: Calling the "Log.d(Header,Body)" function. Using Android Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most probably a number such as `18142-18297` refers to process identifier (in this case `18142`) and thread identifier (`18297`).

**Edit**

The `main` thread seems to have the id of the process. In your case `18142` is the 
id of the `main` thread and other ids such as: 18279 and 18291 refer to other threads created within your application. In the `Thread` window of `DDMS` view you can see all available threads in your application and their ids.
In Eclipse it would look like this: 
[image]

Comment: Is there any documentation to this effect?

Comment: i dont know any specific documentation but Eclipse, as @Abdellah mentioned, gives a better view of those parameters identified as process and thread id.

Answer (score 11):

I think from eclipse it was quite clear

[image]

For the answer to your question refer you to this link  [*: Processes and Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html)